# Can you understand this message?

Tags: cipher

This is an interesting code I came across. Can you understand the following message?

Yqf3 697 r97he 5y3 qhw234?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE. You may want to provide some hints or otherwise make this question more approachable - please see [Code Puzzles: What (Not) To Do](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1717/5373) on meta.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! I recommend reading [Code Puzzles: What (Not) To Do](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/code-puzzles-what-not-to-do). Also, if you found this puzzle somewhere, you must give credit - where is this from?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course we can understand this message!

> The answer is actually on your keyboard. Go down one letter on your QWERTY keyboard and you will read the following (i.e. Y will be H):

This will lead to:

> "Have you found the answer?"

Comment: wow you're fast! too easy??

Comment: If he's right, make sure you mark his answer as accepted!

Comment: You did not use zxcvbnm. That made it easy.